# How to expose session variables to express views

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I'm trying to access session variables in EJS views, but facing lots of problems.

To access the req.session locally I'm using middleware as described here [Accessing Express.js req or session from Jade template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331776/accessing-express-js-req-or-session-from-jade-template)

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('./models/db.js');

var routes = require('./routes/route.js');
var user = require('./routes/user.js');
var story = require('./routes/story.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var app = express();


app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});



app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret:"qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujm"}));


app.get('/',routes.home);

app.get('/register',routes.register);
app.post('/newUser',user.doCreate);

app.get('/login',routes.login);
app.post('/authenticate',user.login);

app.get('/new-story',routes.newStory);
app.post('/add-story',story.addStory);


app.get('/stories/:story',story.getStory);
app.post('/stories/:slug/saveComment',story.saveComment);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var server=app.listen(port,function(req,res){
    console.log("Catch the action at http://localhost:"+port);
});
```

Here is the route.js for handling home route

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Story = mongoose.model( 'Story' );
exports.home=function(req,res){
             Story.find({}, function(err,stories){
                  res.render('home',{stories:stories});
              });
}
```

In the home.ejs I am checking whether user is logged in or note by checking whether username property is set or not.

```
<% if( typeof(session.username) !== 'undefined' ) {%
<h1>Welcome</h1><%=session.username%>
<%}%>
```

But, on accessing the main page I get error saying 
**Cannot read property 'username' of undefined** [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GANhc.jpg)

I am setting the username in session once is user is authenticated.

```
exports.login=function(req,res){
    var email=req.body.email;
    var password=req.body.password;

    User.findOne({email:email}, function(err,user){

      if(err){
        res.redirect("/login");
      }

     user.comparePassword(password,function(err,isMatch){
       if(isMatch && isMatch==true){
         console.log("Authentication Sucessfull");
         req.session.username=user.username;
         console.log("Got USer : "+req.session.username);
         res.redirect("/");
       }else{
         console.log("Authentication UnSucessfull");
         res.redirect("/login");
       }

     });

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Express runs middleware in order of their declaration.

You have this:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
...
app.use(session({secret:"qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujm"}));
```

Your middleware runs before the session middleware (it's declared before it), so you create `res.locals.session` before the session middleware gets a chance to create `req.session`.

Try moving your middleware to *after* the session middleware:

```
app.use(session({secret:"qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujm"}));
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
```